# R import csv lose date (day) value

Tags: r, csv, read.csv, as.date

I am importing a csv, and it stores dates as month-year (Apr-02 for April 2002). In the csv file, there is a day in the value. So Apr-02 would actually have a value in the file as something like 4/10/2002. When I import the file into R, it keeps that Apr-02 format and stores it as a factor. I tried to use

```
ds$val <- as.Date(ds$val, format = "%b-%y")
```

to get it as a date, but it results in all NAs. I can do

```
ds$val <- strptime(paste("1", as.character(ds$val)), format="%d %b-%y")
```

but I lose the day. Is there a way to get the full date when importing the csv (aside from changing the format in the csv file)?

Thanks!

EDIT:[first 5 rows in original format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLYD6.jpg)

Attached image of the csv data, in the first is the original format.

If I change the dates to normal format, values are:
4/10/2002, 8/24/1997, 1/6/1999, 10/10/2008, 8/16/1985

Comment: If it is stored as `"Apr-02"` in text in a csv, I don't understand how it has a day. Is this an Excel formatting issue?

Comment: A date must have all of a day, month _and_ year. If all the values in your file have the same day, just different month/years, then you'll need to add that day before trying to convert it to a date.

Comment: Agree with @thelatemail. Excel does a bunch of things when saving a file as csv. Open the csv in notepad++ and you will be surprised but it's not that excel didn't warn you before saving it as csv...

Comment: @thelatemail it is stored as a date, with a custom format "Apr-02". So there is actually a day in the value, but not in the displayed value. If I go into my csv file and change "Apr-02" to a normal date format, it will display as 4/10/2002 as an example. Changing the format for each csv is a possible solution, but I would like a programatic way of solving it. The dates are not all the same day. Adding a few rows of data to the original post

Comment: You don't have a csv then, you have an Excel file. A csv is plain text, with no formatting or fanciness whatsoever. I can only assume you have to change the formats in the Excel file to start with before importing.

Answer (score 1):

If you use stringsAsFactors=FALSE with the read.csv call you will not get factors but rather character values. But that's not the real problem, since as.Date will accept factors.  You cannot use `as.Date` unless you paste a day-of-the-month value or use the zoo-pkg's `yearmon`-class.